# Symfony4 twig for loop through variable variable

Tags: twig, symfony4

i have a lot of sub entities, so i want to add/update them reusing one controller, view.
So i need before every form print out list of sub entities already created.
Sub entity name is variable

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
<table class="table">
    {% for entity in parentEntity.{{  subEntityName }} %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ entity }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But this is not working, also

```
~ subEntityName ~
```

Not works

Cant find any suggestion. Is possible to use variables in twig loop definition

Answer (score 1):

Found solution

```
{% set entities =  attribute(parentEntity, entityName) %}
{% for entity in entities %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ entity }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And this works for me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new variable `entities`, you can also simply do:

```
{% for entity in attribute(parentEntity, entityName) %}
```

And instead of using the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html), you can use the bracket notation, at least if `parentEntity` is an array:

```
{% for entity in parentEntity[entityName] %}
```